How to install Déjà Dup Backups on Ubuntu 24.04 without snap?
Just installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I can't find it in the Software App repository. However there is a Gnome App.
I don't like Snap or Flathub.
Any idea?
Thanks

You can not find what in the Software App?

It's installed as .deb by default :)
